# optimisation queries in rails with checking includes in list

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

I have six models. `User`, `Channel`, `FeedArticle`, `Comment` and `Relationship` model for connection `User` and `Channel`, and `UserArticle` for user's favourite articles .

This is my relationships:

[image: my relationships]

Each user have some channels, and, accordingly with this channels, he has articles,  I take it, like this:

```
@articles = FeedArticle.find(:all,
       joins: "INNER JOIN relationships on feed_articles.channel_id = relationships.channel_id",
       conditions: "relationships.user_id = #{current_user.id} and relationships.channel_id  in (#{current_user.channels.map(&:id).join(',')})")
```

So two users can have the same articles, if they have the same channels. But each user have unique comments for his article, and unique favourite articles.

And problem for me is: I checked for every article, have it comment for this user?, and also check for favourite. I do that like this:

Check comments:

```
current_user.comments.where(feed_article_id: article.id)
```

And favourites:

```
current_user.user_articles.where(feed_article_id: article.id).present?
```

It's works, but on each article, I have two queries:

```
(0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user_articles" WHERE "user_articles"."user_id" = 3 AND "user_articles"."feed_article_id" = 45
  UserArticle Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "user_articles".* FROM "user_articles" WHERE "user_articles"."user_id" = 3 AND "user_articles"."feed_article_id" = 45 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_remove_from_favourite.html.haml (6.9ms)
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" = 3 AND "comments"."feed_article_id" = 45
  Rendered layouts/_add_comment.html.haml (12.8ms)
```

How can I optimize this queries? Or it better to use pagination and don't worry about it?